# Nodejs why are arrays initialized with prototype static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, prototype

Consider the following code

```
Class = function()
{
    //this.array = [];
}

Class.prototype.array = [];
Class.prototype.str = null;

var a = new Class();
var b = new Class();

a.array.push("a");
console.log (a.array);
b.array.push("b");
console.log (b.array);

a.str = "a";
console.log (a.str);
console.log (b.str);
b.str = "b";
console.log (a.str);
console.log (b.str);
```

If we were to run it as is, we would notice that modifying Class's `array` in any of its instances is done statically - changes to array in `a` are reflected in `b` and vice-versa. However, modifying the `str` variable, although initialized the same way as `array` is not done statically.

If we uncomment the line in the constructor, changes to array in any instances are not done statically anymore.

Did I stumble upon a nodejs bug ? I couldn't find details about this situation anywhere, so could anyone please explain why does nodejs have this behavior ?

Comment: There's no difference between the behavior in Node and in browsers. This is just the way JavaScript works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignments to object properties (**directly** to object properties) always results in a property on the target object itself. *Lookups* of properties, on the other hand, will consult the prototype chain.

When you alter the contents of the array that's present on the prototype:

```
a.array[0] = "foo";
```

you're modifying the object found when the property "array" is looked up via the object "a".  The value is found on the prototype, so that's the value used in the property value assignment. That statement is, structurally:

```
(someObject)[0] = "foo";
```

and here "someObject" is that array found on the prototype.

Here, however, you're setting a property directly on an object:

```
a.str = "foo";
```

JavaScript always creates or updates a property directly on the target object in this case, and won't touch the prototype chain at all.

Comment: So basically `a.array` and `b.array` are references to `Class.prototype.array` ? Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I come from a C++ background.

Comment: Right - the "array" property is not present on the instances (unless you un-comment that line in the constructor), so it's found on the prototype. It's a good idea to forget everything you know from C++ about classes and inheritance, because though JavaScript *looks* similar, it's very much different.

Comment: @Pointy, do you mean reference object? ie (typeof dataType == 'object'), it seems your reasoning works well for reference object as well.. (ie a.myObject.anyProperty="anyValue" would effectively have the same effect on b.myObject.anyProperty="anyValue") once u assign a.myObject.anyProperty, b.myObject.anyProperty would have the same value

Comment: @achan yes - arrays are really not much different from regular objects, so yes if "array" were just a plain object everything (as far as this question and my answer are concerned) would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. By doing

```
Class.prototype.array = [];
```

you create a **shared** attribute. But by doing

```
instance.array = []
```

you create an instance attribute which is neither shared nor visible across instances. By doing `this.array = [];` in constructor you just override the shared reference.